# Keeping text at center bottom in a cell of table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to place text at center and at the bottom of the cell in table. How can I do this?

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: for future reference, when you make a demo image, maybe you can crop it down to the necessary space rather than using up so much white space.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

CSS:

```
td {vertical-align:bottom;text-align:center;}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/vKPG8/

Answer (score 3):

valign="bottom" might work.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp

But I think that's deprecated.

So you should do it in CSS with:

```
<td style="vertical-align:bottom;">your text</td>
```

Comment: `valign` is depreciated and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{
  vertical-align:bottom;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" width="100%">bottom and center</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">TOTAL</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td rowspan="1">TOTAL</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

use style vertical-align:bottom;text-align:center; these can be helpful for your table.